# Equivalent of new Date().getTime() in Java 8

Tags: java, timestamp, java-time

Before Java 8 I was using in code `new Date().getTime()` to obtain current timestamp as number. Can I assume that `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()` is safe equivalent to the legacy way? Does it have exactly the same behavior and similar performance characteristics? Are there any better alternatives?

I want to use the Java 8 way in ecosystem where all surrounding components still use `new Date().getTime()`, so produced results must be consistent.

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` it's old but probably the same that the other classes are using

Comment: "Before Java 8 I was using in code" You could have simply been using [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Date.java#l165).

Comment: Side note: you can do `Instant instantFromDate = new Date().toInstant()` too ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`, `new Date().getTime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` will give you the number of milliseconds since epoch.

From CPU power and memory allocation point of view, you should use `System.currentTimeMillis()` because it's a native method that delegates the task to the underlying operating system (this calculation usually is very optimized and doesn't require garbage collection etc).

Answer (score 5):

### Two options

1. `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`, as you said
2. `System.currentTimeMillis()` as Andy Turner and Marteng said

The choice between the two a matter of taste. `Instant` is the modern replacement for `Date` and to many the natural choice. Use it if you want to give a modern impression. `System.currentTimeMillis()` is as old as `Date`. While `Date` is decidedly poorly designed and should be avoided always, I am not aware of any design problems with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

### Even more modern: keep the Instant

Using a `long` to represent a point in time is very low-level and hard to debug because we don’t naturally assign any meaning to the number. If you can, instead of keeping a number, keep an `Instant`. It also gives you an even finer resolution than milliseconds (since Java 9 `Instant.now()` has a precision of microseconds on many platforms).

### Safe and performant?

> Can I assume that `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()` is safe equivalent to
>   the legacy way? Does it have exactly the same behavior and similar
>   performance characteristics?

Yes, it is safe and equivalent and has similar performance characteristics.

Only under all circumstances avoid `Date` and `Calendar`. They are poorly designed and long outdated and have modern replacements.

Comment: In my case I cannot keep an `Instant` as I need to serialize data into human readable JSON format. Other way would be to represent current time as ISO timestamp, however we chose `long` for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Had it been me, I would have picked ISO 8601 (like `2019-09-11T07:23:18.485924Z`) for human readability and simplicity of debugging, but you have to make your choice for your situation.

Comment: We mainly compare timestamps (it's not relevant when an event occurred, but which was first), so number and comparing with standard operators like `<` won.

Comment: "long to represent a point in time is very low-level and hard to debug". Not if you know it is supposed to be a time, and I would argue often you do. Here (where there are two wrapper choices available) it is the canonical representation.